# Octez-baker-PtLima "command not found

Tags: baker

Ive setup my node, its bootstrapped, I have my ledger connected and I've registered as delegate. However, whenever I try to run

octez-baker-PtLima run with local node ~/.tezos-node ledger

It says command not found. Help?

Answer (score 1):

try `octez-baker-PtLimaPt` instead of `octez-baker-PtLima`.